# Get osx screencapture terminal tool to capture both screens

Tags: macos, screen-capture

The `screencapture` terminal app is perfect and takes a screenshot just like you would expect, but it does only take a screenshot of the main window if you have two screens connected.

```
screencapture screenshot.png
```

But if you do `CMD + Shift + 3` it takes both screens and saves them as two screenshots.

The man page has a parameter `-m`, which says `Only capture the main monitor`, but as you can see i do not use that parameter and you would then assume it would take of both screens, but no.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/screencapture.1.html

How can i make screencapture take both screen or program it to take a screenshot of the second screen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Found the solution 3 minutes later, but thought I would share the information since others would properly need it also :)*

If you have multiple screens you will have to pass more file names, so if you have two screens you would do:

```
screencapture screen1.png screen2.png
```

The functionality is hidden is this message if you read carefully!

```
files   where to save the screen capture, 1 file per screen
```

Answer (score 1):

This script works:

```
while [ 1 ]; do 
  date=$(date "+%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
  screencapture -x -D 1 ~/Desktop/"screen_${date}.png"
  sleep 2
 
  date=$(date "+%Y%m%dT%H%M%S")
  screencapture -x -D 2 ~/Desktop/"screen_${date}.png"
  sleep 2
done
```

The -D 1 and -D 2 command refer to the monitors connected